Почему игнорируется второй хендлер aiogram 3?
Использую FSM
class pub(StatesGroup):
    auth_info = State()
    auth_city = State()
    auth_caption = State()
    auth_photo = State()
    auth_result = State()
    auth_bh = State()

Код:
    @dp.callback_query(pub.auth_result)
async def callbacks_city(callback: CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    if callback.data == "yes":
        data = await state.get_data()
        auth_info = data.get("auth_info")
        auth_city = data.get("auth_city")
        auth_caption = data.get("auth_caption")
        auth_photo = data.get("auth_photo")
        button1 = InlineKeyboardButton(text="Да", callback_data="select_yes")
        button2 = InlineKeyboardButton(text="Нет", callback_data="select_no")
        button3 = InlineKeyboardButton(text="Бан", callback_data="select_ban")
        keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup(inline_keyboard=[[button1], [button2], [button3]])
        redact = await bot.send_photo(chat_id=-1002047364016, photo=auth_photo, caption=auth_caption, reply_markup=keyboard)
        await bot.send_message(-1002047364016, f"Город: {auth_city}\nID автора: {auth_info}")
        await callback.message.answer("Объявление отправлено на модерацию.")
        await state.update_data(auth_result=redact)
        await state.set_state(pub.auth_bh)
    else:
        await state.update_data(auth_result="yes")
        await callback.message.answer("Публикация отменена!")
        await state.clear()

@dp.callback_query(pub.auth_bh)
async def calks_city(callback: CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    await state.update_data(auth_bh="Ура, епт")
    if callback.data == "select_yes":
        data = await state.get_data()
        auth_info = data.get("auth_info")
        auth_city = data.get("auth_city")
        auth_caption = data.get("auth_caption")
        auth_photo = data.get("auth_photo")
        auth_result = data.get("auth_result")
        username = (await bot.get_chat(auth_info)).username
        if username:
            link=f"https://t.me/{username}"
        else:
            link=f"tg://openmessage?user_id={auth_info}"
        button1 = InlineKeyboardButton(text="Опубликовать обьявление", url="не скажу")
        button2 = InlineKeyboardButton(text="Автор объявления", url=link)
        keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup(inline_keyboard=[[button1], [button2]])
        if auth_city == "Тюмень":
            CHATID = tumen_id
        else:
            CHATID = null_id
        await bot.send_photo(chat_id=CHATID, photo=auth_photo, caption=auth_caption, reply_markup=keyboard)
        await bot.send_message(-1002047364016, f"Одобрено! Модератор: {callback.from_user.id}", reply_to_message_id=auth_result.id)
        await bot.send_message(auth_info, f"Ваше обьявление опубликовано модераторами!")
        await state.clear()
    else:
        data = await state.get_data()
        auth_info = data.get("auth_info")
        auth_city = data.get("auth_city")
        auth_caption = data.get("auth_caption")
        auth_photo = data.get("auth_photo")
        auth_result = data.get("auth_result")
        await bot.send_message(-1002047364016, f"Отказ! Модератор: {callback.from_user.id}", reply_to_message_id=auth_result.id)
        await bot.send_message(auth_info, f"Ваше обьявление отклонено модераторами!")
        await state.clear()

Конечно это не весь код, но проблема зарыта где то здесь

Логи в cmd при нажатии на кнопку: INFO:aiogram.event:Update id=263119381 is not handled. Duration 0 ms by bot id=7365040484
